# Heroku application error on Celery: raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I am trying to deploy my Django app on Heroku. Whenever I go to my app I am getting an error:

```
2020-09-06T20:31:59.000436+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
2020-09-06T20:31:59.000477+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty
```

I have now two settings file so in my projects folder which contains the `wsgi.py`. I have a folder called `settings/` which is:

```
settings
--common.py
--development.py
--productions.py
```

In my `production.py` I have:

```
from register.settings.common import *
import os
import django_heroku

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1','appname.heroku.com']

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

And in my `wsgi.py` and `manage.py` I have:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'register.settings.production')
```

Now I have added the Postgres add-on from the dashboard and can check that I also have it using the Heroku CLI.

I have also added a custom domain name of `www.myapp.com` as well which I do not know if this is causing the issue.

For pushing to master I did:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

and then:

```
git push heroku master
```

What is causing this issue? When I do `python manage.py run server` I also get the error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I also get this error in my Heroku logs when I check it how can I set the secret key?

**EDIT 2**

The issue seems to be with my `celery.py` file, however, I have tried changing the settings to point to `production.py` (register in my projects root folder):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
import django

app = Celery('register')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

in my `manage.py` I have:

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'register.settings.development')` Which the command `manage.py runserver` works however, now I get an error:

```
8:52:21 PM web.1 |      raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
8:52:21 PM web.1 |  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

in this line in my wsgi.py file:

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'register.settings.production')`
`application = get_wsgi_application()`

Comment: Have you set a `SECRET_KEY` config var (environment variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply haven't set your `SECRET_KEY`.

You try to import it from the environment in your `settings` module, but this depends on an environment variable called `SECRET_KEY` existing:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

On Heroku, the best way to set this environment varialbe is to set a [config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). This can be done with the Heroku CLI:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=some_value
```

or in the web dashboard.

Comment: I have done this in the web dashboard however, celery.py is still giving me an error. Should I restart the server for changes to take effect?

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart your server. Does _Django_ work now, e.g. does `heroku run python manage.py migrate` raise an `ImproperlyConfigured` error? It shouldn't.

Comment: There seems to be an error with my celery.py file. I have tried setting the `autodiscover_tasks` according to my new settings file however I am getting an error

Comment: Well, you said you also got the problem with `manage.py runserver`. Let's fix _that_. I think this should do that. _Then_, we can deal with your Celery file.

Comment: So `Heroku run python manage.py migrate` I was able to run this command successfully however when I do `heroku local web` I get the above error from my celery.py file. I also get the same error when I do `manage.py runserver`. I have edited my celery.py configuration

Comment: Okay, so why are you trying to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your script?

Comment: Yes I noticed the issue there, after removing that and changing the the line in manage.py `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'register.settings.development')` now the command `manage.py runserver` works however `heroku local web` still gives me the same error.

Comment: @ashes999, if you modify your code you need to also modify your _question_. You can't expect us to keep track of comments and try to figure out what your code does... please read [ask].